# How can I save my scraped JSON dataset that is a text format into my local machine and also how can I read the file into Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, pandas, imdb

This is how the code looks like below:
I want to use it for analysis

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

> {"@type":"imdb.api.title.ratings","id":"/title/tt0944947/","title":"Game of Thrones","titleType":"tvSeries","year":2011,"canRate":true,"otherRanks":[{"id":"/chart/ratings/toptv","label":"Top 250 TV","rank":12,"rankType":"topTv"}],"rating":9.2,"ratingCount":1885115,"ratingsHistograms":{"Males Aged 18-29":{"aggregateRating":9.3,"demographic":"Males Aged 18-29","histogram":{"1":11186,"2":693,"3":801,"4":962,"5":2103,"6":3583,"7":9377,"8":22859,"9":52030,"10":174464},"totalRatings":278058},"IMDb Staff":{"aggregateRating":8.7,"demographic":"IMDb Staff","histogram":{"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":1,"6":3,"7":6,"8":19,"9":27,"10":17},"totalRatings":73}

Comment: if you have it as single string then simply use `open()`, `write()`, `close()`

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, you should find it in any tutorial for Python or in many examples for `requests`

```
fh = open("output.json")
fh.write(response.text)
fh.close()
```

or

```
with open("output.json") as fh:
    fh.write(response.text)
```

---

As for pandas you can try to read it

```
df = pd.read_json("output.json")
```

or you can use module `io` to read it without saving on disk

```
import io

fh = io.StringIO(response.text)
df = pd.read_json(fh)
```

But `pandas` keeps data as table with rows and columns but you have nested lists/dicts so it may need some work to keep it in `DataFrame`.

If you want to get only some data from `json` then you could use `response.json()`